# How do I find and replace data(coming from DB) inside HTML tags in VB.NET?

Tags: html, regex, database, vb.net, telerik

`Hello<span style="white-space:pre;">          </span>World`

This is the HTML which is being fetched from the DB. I want to replace the white-space inside the span tag with "&nbsp;" How do I achieve this in VB.NET? The replacement should happen only if there are more than 2 whitespaces next to each other. Each instance of white-space should be replaced by &nbsp;

Main aim of doing replacing white-space by "&nbsp;" is because ITextSharp cannot retain the white-space while converting it to a PDF.

PS: The HTML is created by a Telrik editor, and stored in a DB

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please share so that we could help you fix it.

Comment: I have tried out this RegEx to match 2 or more whitespaces: `<.*>\s{2,}</.*>`. But I am unable to replace it with &nbsp; iff there are 2 or more whitespaces, and in the correct positions

Comment: I am not sure what you need: `Hello<span&nbsp;style="white-space:pre;">          </span>World` (then use `Regex.Replace(s, "(?<=<span[^>]*?)\s", "&nbsp;")`) or `Hello<span style="white-space:pre;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>World` (then use `Regex.Replace(s, "(?<=<span[^>]*>[^<]*?)\s(?=[^<]*</span>)", "&nbsp;")`)?